# How can I pass Hyperlink value from Gridview column on one page into KPIFrame.Attributes("SRC") in another page

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, iframe

I am working a fairly basic web based KPI system and am struggling to get my head round this problem.

I have a top level page which has Gridview containing various items we are tracking and their current status. There is also a Hyperlink field that provides links to external pages / data. I need to open these links within a frame in the current site to maintain the look and feel of it.

If I hard code the src value for the iFrame it works fine but what I need to do is pass the URL contained in the LeafURL field into the KPIFrame.Attributes("SRC") = "Need something here"

so the question is how do I call the URL details from the previous page and inject it into the iFrame src field on the new page.

This is the code on my main page. Somehow I need the next page to pick up the linktext(LeafURL) value from the Gridview on this page.

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim linknew As HyperLink
        Dim linktext as String

        linktext = e.Row.DataItem("LeafURL")
        linknew = e.Row.FindControl("Hyperlink1")

                  If e.Row.DataItem("Status") = "0" Or "1" Then
            linknew.NavigateUrl = ("~/leaf.aspx")

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not clearly understand your question but if you want to pass value from one page to another then you can use querystring as ` Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?var=134") in the second page you can get it as string var = Request.QueryString("var").ToString()`

Comment: Hello,  What I have is a Gridview column that contains URL values for links to external data. When the user clicks on the link it opens new page (Leaf.aspx) which is a blank page which needs to load the contents of the selected URL into a Frame. What I am trying to do is pull the URL information from the first page and pass the value into the iFrame src value in the second page so that the requested data is displayed within a frame in the new page. Hope this makes sense, still pretty new to this and got a lot of learning to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted now. The solution lay in correctly constructing the querystring on the 1st page so that is could be referenced on the 2nd page. As shown below:

Code on 1st Page:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim linktext As String = e.Row.DataItem("URL")
    Dim linknew As HyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1")

    linknew.Text = linktext

    linknew.NavigateUrl = "~/Leaf.aspx?URL=" + e.Row.DataItem("URL")
```

Code on 2nd Page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    KPIframe.Attributes("SRC") = Request.QueryString("URL")

    Label1.Text = Request.QueryString("URL")

End Sub
```

Turned out to be much simpler than it first appeared to solve this problem.

Now have system working where the URL value in the GridView on page 1 is passed to page 2 and used to determine the src value for the iframe on that page.